# How to convert the DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm format to epoch time using moment or js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I have a date time picker and it omits date in format of a `DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm a` format. I want to convert it into epoch time to store it in the database backend.
I have tried using the following methods so far, but all of them return `NaN` as output:

```
var loadingPlannedUnTime = this.state.loadingPlannedUnTime;
console.log("normal conversion"+loadingPlannedUnTime);
//returns 9-08-2020 15:08:00

//Moment method
var loadingPlannedUnTime = moment(this.state.loadingPlannedUnTime).unix();
console.log("moemnt"+loadingPlannedUnTime)
//Returns NaN

//JS getTime() method 
var pickupDateTime = new Date(this.state.loadingPickupTime);
var loadingPickupTime = pickupDateTime.getTime();
console.log("new date and gettime"+loadingPickupTime)
//Returns NaN
```

What is the correct method to convert it to epoch time?

Comment: edited my answer for your specific case

Comment: you can do that simply with this `new Date(loadingPlannedUnTime).getTime() / 1000`
for your data `console.log(new Date("9-08-2020 15:08:00").getTime() / 100)` returns 1599566880

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://momentjs.com/docs/

If you know the format of an input string, you can use that to parse a moment.

```
moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");
```

```js
const x = moment('24-12-2019 09:15', "DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm");
console.log(x.format())
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: why dont you use day.js for this simple task?

Comment: @Ifaruki because the title of the question says 'moment'

Answer (score 1):

```
const matches = loadingPlannedUnTime.match(/(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{2,4}) (\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})/);
if (!!matches) {
    // new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
    const epoch = new Date(matches[3], matches[2] - 1, matches[1], matches[4], matches[5], matches[6]).getTime();
    console.log(epoch);
}
```